# Graphical Models: Marginalization of Intermediate Node

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I'm trying to infer the rules for the marginalization of a random variable in a graphical model. I've become stuck with the following.

Give a graph of the form,

[image: Simple Graphical Model]

the probability density function can be written as : 
$$P(A,B,C) = P(C|B)P(B|A)P(A)$$
Let us now say that we wish to marginalize out B, then 
$$P(A,C) = \int_{B} P(C|B)P(B|A)P(A)$$
I have been doing this using the following logic,
$$\int_B P(C|B)P(B|A)P(A) = \int_B P(C,B|A)P(A) = P(C|A)P(A)$$
Is such a method correct? I'm fairly confident the result is, but I think the method is incorrect. If this is not correct, are there a specific set of rules that one would follow in this case?

EDIT : We've noted since that the marginalization of a variable is essentially the marginalization in the joint distribution of the markov blanket of the variable.

As, in this case, the entire joint IS the markov blanket of node B then marginalizing B can be seen as $\sum_B P(A,B,C) = P(A,C) = P(C|A)P(A)$ and so we get the correct answer.

However, for a slightly more complex situation, (eg. A->B->C->D) the marginalization would still be over P(A,B,C) (the markov blanket).

I am still extremely interested if there are more rules or intuitions about this (or whether what we've noted here is strictly correct). If any one happens accross this, please let us know :)